# Validar campo Angular

Tags: angular

Hola buenas tengo este campo , y me gustaría saber como puedo validar que solo entren valores numericos sin poner en el html type=number.Con Angular.

```html
 
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="prueba" formControlName="prueba" name="prueba">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 3 opciones actualmente:

- Puedes usar la directiva `pattern` en tu html, seria algo así:

  `<input pattern="[0-9 ]*">`
- Puedes utilizar `Validators.pattern("0-9")` cuando declaras tu FormGroup
- O, lo menos recomendable teniendo en cuenta las dos opciones anteriores sería, hacer tu propio validador.

De todos modos, la mejor opción sería hacer uso del atributo `type="number` en tu plantillas.

https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators